# File replacing in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I need to replace a file with another one on a VFS (having both struct file) in a Linux kernel module. I tried 2 ways of doing that but both have some problems.
So I have 2 files correctly initialized, the first solution was:

```
vfs_truncate(&filp_one->f_path, 0);
err = vfs_copy_file_range(filp_two, 0, filp_one, 0, file_size, 0);
```

where file_size is the size of filp_two, I need the truncate because if the size of filp_one is bigger than filp_two I could have a dirty copy.
In this case, the problem is that another process can modify the file between the two operations and if I try to lock with:

```
inode_lock(filp_one->f_inode);
vfs_truncate(&filp_one->f_path, 0);
err = vfs_copy_file_range(filp_two, 0, filp_one, 0, file_size, 0); 
inode_unlock(filp_one->f_inode);
```

the result is a deadlock.

The other solution and maybe better I thought was to rename filp_two and then unlink.

```
vfs_rename(parent, filp_two_dentry , parent, filp_one_dentry, NULL, RENAME_WHITEOUT);
```

I also locked with rename_lock, but I omitted because that's not the point.
In this case, the problem is that all the other open file structs after one rename will return an error "already freed". So I wanted to know if exists a way to update the file descriptors avoiding close and open again.
Looking into the source I saw the d_move function [d_move](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/dcache.c#L2869), so I added this line, but nothing changes:

```
d_exchange(filp_one_dentry, filp_two_dentry);
```

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my English

P.S. I know that is not preferable to work with files in this way

Comment: I'm not sure I'm entirely right here, but maybe you could create an inode and allocate blocks without assigning it a path in the filesystem, make the copy to that, and afterwards just swap the pointer in the dentry. Does that make sense? There should be no deadlocks, and the target shouldn't be neither modified nor result in having trailing garbage. I guess someone could change the source file, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if I got your solution. The idea is this sequence: 
create a third tempfile,
copy filp_one there
link the temp file
and swap filp_two_dentry->d_inode with the new one?

Comment: Exactly. Ideally, but I don't remember if that's possible, don't assign to any name in any dentry the temp file, to make sure nobody can modify it to your back.

Comment: filp_two is different from any process, so theoretically I could swap the two inode pointers but I tried in two ways, with d_move and also swapping directly the pointers, but without results.

Comment: IIUC, having `filp_two` being per-process (which it is) doesn't mean nobody else can open the underlying file. That's why I suggested doing the writes in a file that can't be accessed and them swapping. Any previously open file descriptor owned by another process will point to the original one they opened, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous comment was a bit confused. What I meant is that filp_two belongs to an inode that is created and accessed only by the owner. So I think that is what you are saying. But I didn't understand how can I swap the pointers in order to make all the open file pointers, pointing to the renamed file

Comment: OK. No, the swap pointer will only have effect for new opens AFAIK. The previously opened descriptors will point to the original file. At least that's what happens if you delete the file. I didn't get that that was one of the requirements. But yeah, if `filp_two`'s inode belongs only to the current process you're already doing what I suggested.

Comment: So as you know is there a way to don't release the lock between truncate and copy nor make a full copy that overwrites even if filp_one is bigger than filp_two? Takning in account that both truncate and copy takes lock on inode by theirselves?